# How to play a local audio file using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am new to phonegap and am trying to play a local audio file when user clicks on play button
   and pause the audio when user clicks on pause button...

```
and am adding the path 
1) playAudio("/android_asset/fire.mp3");

But it is showing an error in logcat 

 04-17 07:17:20.221: E/Web Console(4558): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Media at      file:///android_asset/www/index.html:29
```

i placed my audio file in asset folder

and I am checking on real device HTC android

Answer (score 3):

You might be trying to call Media before the deviceready event fires.

Something like the below might help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myMedia = null;
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady () {
    myMedia = new Media("/android_asset/www/fire.mp3", 
        function(){
            if (myMedia) {
                myMedia.stop();
                myMedia.release();
            }
        }, 
        function(error){
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    );
}

</script>
```

Comment: I replaced `onDeviceReady()` with `document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);`, but now the function does not even run.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Give src = /android_asset/www/mp3filename.mp3  check it once you may be given

/android_assets/www/mp3filename.mp3

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have a folder named audio in www folder. You may access the local file test.mp3 in it using the code.

```
media = new Media('audio/test.mp3');
```